# How does Javascript change datetime format?

Tags: javascript, html

I got Date string :

```
var myDate = "2013-06-07T19:53:00.001+07:00";
```

How can I change it to :

```
result = "7/6/2013 at 19:53";
```

Comment: Check this : http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html

Comment: tks yours. May I will find before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPvQu/)

```
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var year = d.getFullYear();

var hours = d.getHours();
var mins = d.getMinutes();

var datestring = month + "/" + date + "/" + year + " at " + hours + ":" + mins;
```

Comment: tks for your help much;